# What could cause messaging with Samba to fail?

Tags: networking, samba

Got a Linux and Windows (XP and Vista) home network going. Windows print/file sharing with Samba and native WIndows stuff seems ostensibly to be going fine.

But when I try to "net send" (via smbclient -M) from Linux to a windows box it says either "session request denied" or NT_HOSTNAME_NOT_FOUND (or some such).

Now, I have done this once before on the exact same machines but can't seem to repeat it.

ALso, if I do [nmblookup -B 192.168.1.255 "*"] from the Linux Samba server (192.168.1.255 being my subnet broadcast) should it list all netBios'es on the windows network? currently it lists only the local machine.

THis question is kinda vague but if you have any ideas or pointers then please let me know.

Comment: Yes, messenger service is enabled. Hmmm, back to the drawing board on this one...

Answer (score 2):

In Windows XP SP2 the messenger service is disabled  by default and must be turned on.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839018

In Windows Vista the messenger service is gone completely Vista has the ability to send a net send type message but I am unsure if it can receive one.

http://www.petri.co.il/msg-exe-net-send-vista.htm